# Is it possible to get the radix of a number in Java?

Tags: java, numbers, radix

For the following numbers:

```
int a = 0b1;
int b = 1;
int c = 0x1;
```

I know they all represent the same value but does Java mark their differences somewhere? How can I determine their radices seperately such as

```
getRadix(a) -> 2
getRadix(b) -> 10
getRadix(c) -> 16
```

I'm only asking when the values given are **integral types**.

Comment: *but does Java mark their differences somewhere?* **No**. You can't. All `int` are 32-bits. Always 32-bits.

Comment: They don't have radixes. They're just numbers. You wrote them in particular radixes, but Java doesn't remember what radix you wrote them in.

Comment: `int` is always a signed two's-complement binary number. If you really need a feature like what you're asking for, you could look for a library that does this or write an object which does it yourself.

Comment: @Radiodef Look for a library that does this **how?** The information is lost by the compiler: the literal is compiled into binary.

Comment: @EJP I don't mean from a literal. It would have to be by parsing a `String`. Since the OP didn't tell us why they want this, we don't really have any way of knowing what a solution could be. It seems like a pretty odd request to me, so it must be that they actually need something else, like they want to store numbers in specific radices. I'm sure there's a math library which could do something like that.

Comment: @Radiodef There are no strings in the OP's code. Don't answer a different question, even in comments. And again, 'math library which could do something like' *what*? You can't identify a radix from a string literal. Consider '0'. It is a legal digit in every radix known to mankind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know they all represent the same value but does Java mark their differences somewhere?

No. You did, when you wrote the source code, but the compiler converts them all into binary: no information as to the original radix of the numeric literal is retained.